# Set local address for client socket in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

In my Node.JS application, I initiate a TCP connection to a nearby server.

```
clientSocket = new net.Socket({});
clientSocket.connect(12345, ip, function () { … });
```

The socket uses the primary address of `eth0`, but `eth0` has multiple addresses (within the same subnet). Is it possible to define the local address the socket should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the factory method which returns a `net.Socket`, `net.createConnection`, you can do this.

```
var net = require('net');

var socket = net.createConnection({
    port: 10011,
    host: 'localhost',
    localAddress: '192.168.0.1'
}, function() {
    console.log('connected');
});
```

[Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectionlistener)